# Read AndroidManifest.xml in eclipse plugin code without opening it in IEditor

Tags: eclipse, plugins, android-manifest

First I tried to open it in eclipse editor and then read it using org.eclipse.jface.text.IDocument API. But it is quite lengthy, so I tried to figure out way to directly read the file. Here are the pieces that I have found in this regard.

```java
IProject project = (IProject)((IAdaptable)firstElement).getAdapter(IProject.class);
IPath path = project.getFullPath();
String strr=path.toString();

IFile manifest = project.getFile("AndroidManifest.xml");
IPath file_path = manifest.getFullPath().makeAbsolute();
```

Now, I can use getContents() method of IFile interface. But how to read the contents as it appears in editor(Eclipse editor or IEditor) as I have no idea how AndroidManifest.xml is encoded.

Comment: What do you mean by `as it appears in editor`?

Comment: IEditor or Eclipse editor